# Socket Mobile and Web Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, socketscan, web-bluetooth

Hey Socket Mobile team,

I was wondering if you have plans on integrating with Web Bluetooth. I've tried connecting to my Socket Mobile D750 from chrome://bluetooth-internals on Chrome version 59.0 but I'm getting an error that says Unsupported_Device.

I have the scanner in HID mode. Chrome's documentation says that it supports BLE 4.0, but I couldn't find which version of BLE your scanners have.

Answer (score 0):

**No plans right now.**

At the time of writing, none of our barcode scanners have BLE. The recently announced [D600 RFID reader](https://www.socketmobile.com/about-us/press-releases/2017/02/13/socket-mobile-unveils-durascan-d600-contactless-reader-writer) uses BLE and supports reading using HID mode or a GATT profile - but you wouldn't be able to write tags

However, the upcoming Capture SDK uses HTTP on Android and Windows to communicate between your app and the service. If you are targeting those platforms and are okay with being on the bleeding edge, you could write your own Javascript client.

Comment: Is the reason for the new Capture SDK not supporting iOS is because mobile Safari does not support Web Bluetooth yet? If so, when/if Mobile Safari adds support for it, will the Capture SDK add support for iOS?

Comment: No, Capture SDK does not require (or use) Web Bluetooth. The iOS version is in the works.

Comment: Where can i download the Capture SDK to start playing around with it?

Comment: It's on the [developer portal](http://www.socketmobile.com/developer/portal/capture-sdk)

Comment: Thanks. I'd be interested in building a javascript client. Is there info on what I should be listening for from the socket mobile companion app? Is it using websockets to send the the data over?

Comment: That's great! The over-the-wire docs haven't been published yet, but I'll try to do it today. I'll post the link here when they are up

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward to it.

Comment: Just a quick update: I'm still working on the docs. Hopefully, I can send you something Monday. If not, it will have to be Wednesday.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again for the quick replies!

Comment: Here's the [link to the Capture json-rpc docs](http://docs.socketmobile.com/capture-preview/json-rpc/en/latest/)! We tried to follow the [jsonrpc spec](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) pretty closely, but there are a few differences. We do not currently support positional params or batched requests.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much Enrico. I'll take a look and let you know if I have anymore questions

Comment: @Enrico I know this is an old post, but when creating an appkey for Capture JS, what do I use as the bundle ID? Also, will this SDK work if the Socket Companion app is backgrounded and another iOS app is in the foreground (and actively paired with the Socket Mobile scanner)?

Comment: @policenauts No, I don't think iOS apps can interact with the scanner while in the background - even if the foreground app is not using the scanner. But please email developers@socketmobile.com to double check.